# Building sum of dynamic number of rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My df looks something like the first three columns of the following:

```
ID VAL LENGTH SUM
1  1   1      1
1  1   1      1
1  1   2      2
1  1   2      2
2  0   1      0
2  3   1      0
2  4   2      3
```

I want to add a fourth column, which is defined as the sum of the group's first to LENGTH-st values in VAL.

How do I do that?

Comment: Could you explain what -st means?

Comment: What I want to say is that the row's value in LENGTH determines the number of observations I want to add: LENGTH is equal to 1 for the first two rows, so SUM is the sum of only the first observation of VAL. For the third row, LENGTH is equal to 2, so SUM equals the sum of VAL for the first two observations.

Comment: maybe in data.table: `setDT(d)[, sum2 := cumsum(VAL)[LENGTH], by=ID]`, so in dplyr i guess `group_by(ID) %>% mutate(SUM2 = cumsum(VAL)[LENGTH])` might work

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(SUM = sapply(LENGTH, function(x) sum(VAL[1:x])))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID   VAL LENGTH   SUM
  <int> <int>  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1      1     1
2     1     1      1     1
3     1     1      2     2
4     1     1      2     2
5     2     0      1     0
6     2     3      1     0
7     2     4      2     3
```

Comment: Why use `!=0`?!

Comment: Thanks @NelsonGon, indeed not needed - I made a mistake in the way I copied the OP's `df` and haven't re-checked.